# Why is returning a constructor allowed in operator overloading?

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading

Why is returning a constructor allowed in operator overloading?

Here is an example:

```
Complex Complex::operator*( const Complex &operand2 ) const
{
    double Real = (real * operand2.real)-(imaginary * operand2.imaginary);
    double Imaginary = ( real * operand2.imaginary)+(imaginary * operand2.real);

    return Complex ( Real, Imaginary );
}
```

It seems to be returning a constructor for the object and not the object itself? What is it returning there?

This seems to make more sense:

```
Complex Complex::operator*( const Complex &operand2 ) const
{
    double Real = (real * operand2.real)-(imaginary * operand2.imaginary);
    double Imaginary = ( real * operand2.imaginary)+(imaginary * operand2.real);

    Complex somenumber ( Real, Imaginary );

    return somenumber;
}
```

Comment: `Complex(...)` is the construction of an *instance* of `Complex`. The constructor is used to initialize an object of that type, in this case, a temporary.

Comment: "returning a constructor"??? What on Earth made you conclude that it is "returning a constructor"? In C++ language constructors have names like `Complex::Complex`. Note - two identical parts separated by a `::`. That would be a constructor name. Now, where do you see anything that would look like a constructor in the code you posted?

Comment: Why not `return {Real, Imaginary};`?

Comment: I have never seen that syntax before. Does the syntax work same as how Matt answered below?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C++ the syntax: *Typename ( arguments )* means to create an unnamed object (aka. a temporary object) of type *Typename* <sup>1</sup>. The arguments are passed to the constructor of that object (or used as initializers for primitive types).

It is very similar in meaning to your second example:

```
Complex somenumber( Real, Imaginary);
return somenumber;
```

the only difference being that the object has a name.

There are some minor differences between the two versions relating to copying or moving the object back to the calling function.  [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

<sup>1</sup> Except when it's [part of a function declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/most-vexing-parse)

Comment: Matt, I edited the second example. Yeah it didn't make much sense since the () operator was not overloaded in Complex.

Comment: As for the copy/move constructor thing you mentioned, is it better to use the first version and return an unnamed temporary object?

Comment: @Overtaker I think they are technically equivalent , although historically some compilers elided case 1 but not case 2. (I'm not completely sure about this though)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help! I see books using case 1, so I may just stick to that. As for Typename (arguments), did you mean to say Class name (arguments)?

Comment: @Overtaker No. A class name is a type name but you can also do it with non-classes (e.g. `return int(5);`